# Android: listview with different items (optimization)

Tags: android, listview

I'm reading this tutorial http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 . I have just a question: if I definire an xml layout like this one:

```
 <LinearLayout>

    <ListView/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/id1" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/id2" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/id3" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/id4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, suppose that to show the item type A I use the Textview id1 and id2: For the item type B I use id1 and the imageview id3. For the item type C id1, id2 and id3. For the item type D the id4, etc etc.
**In a case like this, having textviews and imageviews (in the xml layout) which will not be used by every item in the listview, will it be slow (in performance)?**
Thank you in advance

Comment: Create a seperate layout file for each of your item types.

Comment: A sample ? I don't understand how, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an adapter, you can create a separate layout for each type of item and inflate a different layout in `getView` method of your adapter.

Comment: The matter is that I need to have different type of item in a single layout

Comment: But you just said that based on the item type, some elements of the layout are not used?

Comment: It is possibile. Con you just show me a sample code of what is your solution? Thanks

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680060/is-it-possible-to-inflate-two-layouts-in-arrayadapter-getview-in-android

Comment: Well, I think I'll open another thread to explain better what is my problem